# Static local C variables are followed by a number in assembler code. Is that number random?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, static

I wonder if the number that follows a local static variable name in assembler is random or if there is a meaning.
I compiled a sample C source with gcc v. 4.7.2 in Debian wheezy; the assembler listing shows a row containing:

```
.comm   i.1705,4,4
```

Where does 1705 come from?
Thank you in advance.

Here is the source:

```
int main() { static int i=0; return i; }
```

Comment: You should include the relevant line of  C source, too.

Comment: random and meaning are merely orthogonal in that case. I guess that it is just some random value to distinguish static variables of same name in different functions and/or scopes. IIRC, clang does the same by adding the name of the function to the variable name.

Comment: @Jens.  Yes, I know; you are right.  But I don't know why the suffix number doesn't start from 0001; it seems to me a random number. What do you think about?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably some counter of all identifiers encountered during the compilation. If I put another declaration just behind, it gives me the next number. If I put another, non-static, object in between the difference is 2.

Comment: I agree.  But still unknown where the first number comes from. I also tried compiling the following sample C source: int foo(int j) { static int i=0; return i+j; } int main() { static int i=0; return foo(i); } which shows two symbols: i.1709, i.1706.  It's not clear to me the +3 increment.  And also: 1706, 1709 may be offsets?  From what?

Comment: The only way to know for this level of detail are the compiler sources.